# Interface implementation override type of another interface

Tags: c#

I have an interface `IArticle` with several implementations: `ProductType`,`RawMaterial`,`PaintType`, etc.

Then I have what I consider a reference (SKU) that is a composite element between an `IArticle`and a `Color`:

```
public interface IReference
{
    Color Color { get; set; }
    IArticle Article { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have several implementations, each one has a corresponding IArticle implementation:

- `Product : IReference` will have a `ProductType` as `Article`,
- `SemifinishedGood: IReference` will have a `RawMaterial` as `Article`
- `Paint : IReference` will have a `PaintType` as `Article`

So the thing is... how can I override the `Article` type, something like this:

```
public class Paint: IReference
{
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    public virtual PaintType Article { get; set; }
}
```

So that I can access `PaintType` specific properties instead of only being an `IArticle` when I'm dealing with a `Paint.Article` without having to cast everytime? What is wrong in this architecture?

Comment: So, why `public virtual` on your `Paint` implementation? There doesnt seem much reason to do this.

Comment: @Jamiec it's for NHibernate that needs to be virtual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Generic type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) solve this very easily.

```
public interface IReference<TArticle> where TArticle : IArticle
{
    Color Color { get; set; }
    TArticle Article { get; set; }
}

public class Paint : IReference<PaintType>
{
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    public virtual PaintType Article { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 1 second! You should also show how to declare the `Paint` type.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to duplicate the answer. Nicely done.

Comment: There; I combined them :)

Comment: Its not clear why you've used `virtual` for the implementations, `public virtual` is a bit of an antipattern at the best of times

Comment: Jamiec -- that's what the OP asked for. It may be an EF class; they may wish to make it virtual for mocking purposes. They may just like virtual classes.

Comment: It is public virtual for NHibernate